# Symfony order by the content of a specific field

Tags: symfony, sorting, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I want to sort data in repository based on the content of a specific field
For example i have an entity person with the fields role,fistName and lastName.
I would like to sort using `->orderBy('p.role', ???)` and get a list ordered based on this order : professors then directors then teachers and at last students .

Example of my database:

[image]

Wanted result:

[image]

Ps: i can not use ASC or DESC since my sorting order is neither ASC nor DESC;
    it is a custom order

Comment: please share some code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very strage scenario, you could use a [CASE](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#case-expressions) statement in order to assing a custom value for each fields then sort on him.
You could use the [HIDDEN](https://michelsalib.com/2012/03/04/doctrine2-ninja-with-the-hidden-keyword/) keyword.
As example take a look at this DQL:

```
SELECT p, CASE 
            WHEN p.role = "professor" THEN 1 
            WHEN p.role = "director" THEN 2
            WHEN p.role = "teacher" THEN 3
            WHEN p.role = "student" THEN 4
          ELSE 99 END 
            AS HIDDEN mySortRule
 FROM Bundle\Entity\Person p
 ORDER BY mySortRule ASC
```

Hope this help